# Change style of styled component for selected Item

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to change background and text color of selected component.

I used styled component and created isSelected but, don't know how to use `isSelected` to change background and text color.

How to toggle it's value?

I have component like:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  :hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  ${({ isSelected }) =>
    isSelected &&
    `
    background-color: #b4b4b4`}

`;

const SomeText = styled.span`
  color: #000000

    ${({ isSelected }) =>
        isSelected &&
        `
        color: #ffffff`}
`;

const MessageRoom = ({ item, onClick }) => {
 return (
  <Container onClick={onClick}>
   <SomeText>{item.text}</SomeText>
  </Container>
 )
};
```

And above component is list item and following is parent component like:

```
return (
    <div>
        {list.map(item => {
          return <MessageRoom item={item} key={item.id} onClick={onItemClick}/>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
const MessageRoom = ({ item, onClick }) => {
 const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);

 return (
  <Container isSelected={isSelected} onClick={onClick}>
   <SomeText isSelected={isSelected}>{item.text}</SomeText>
  </Container>
 )
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The styled components are otherwise just fine, but `SomeText` is just missing a semicolon:

```
const SomeText = styled.span`
  color: #000000;
  /*            ^^ */
  ${({ isSelected }) => isSelected && `color: #ffffff`}
`;
```

Since the style applied if `isSelected` is true doesn't use any variables, you can also change the backticks into normal quotes:

```
const SomeText = styled.span`
  color: #000000;
  /*            ^^ */
  ${({ isSelected }) => isSelected && "color: #ffffff"}
`;
```

Same applies to `Container`.

To toggle the styles, you just need to pass `isSelected` as a prop to `SomeText` and `Container`, e.g.

```
const MessageRoom = ({ item, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <Container isSelected={true} onClick={onClick}>
      <SomeText isSelected={true}>{item.text}</SomeText>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

How you compute the value for `isSelected` is on you.

Comment: That was the question, how to compute isSelected value. Not sure how can i toggle it?

Comment: I would refer you to [Intro to React](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#making-an-interactive-component).